# Defining overloaded constants in Isabelle

Tags: overloading, isabelle

How can one define a function in Isabelle that has a different definition depending on either the type of its argument, or the type of the context it is used in?

For example, I might want to define a functions `is_default` with type `'a ⇒ bool`, where each different type `'a` has a potentially different "default value". (I am also assuming, for the sake of argument, that existing concepts such as `zero` are not suitable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of overloading looks like a perfect fit for type classes. First you define a type class for your desired function `is_default`:

```
class is_default =
  fixes is_default :: "'a ⇒ bool"
```

Then you introduce arbitrary instances. E.g., for Booleans

```
instantiation bool :: is_default
begin
definition "is_default (b::bool) ⟷ b"
instance ..
end
```

and lists

```
instantiation list :: (type) is_default
begin
definition "is_default (xs::'a list) ⟷ xs = []"
instance ..
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Isabelle supports overloaded definitions by defining a constant name and then later providing the constant with new definitions for different types. This can be done with the `consts` command to define the constant name, and then the `defs (overloaded)` command to provide a partial definition.

For example:

```
consts is_default :: "'a ⇒ bool"

defs (overloaded) is_default_nat:
  "is_default a ≡ ((a::nat) = 0)"

defs (overloaded) is_default_option:
  "is_default a ≡ (a = None)"
```

The above will also work without the `(overloaded)` parameter, but will cause Isabelle to issue a warning.

The `defs` command is also given a name, which is the name of the theorem generated by Isabelle which contains the definition. This name can then be used in later proofs:

```
lemma "¬ is_default (Some 3)"
  by (clarsimp simp: is_default_option)
```

More information is available in section "Constants and definitions" in the [Isablle/Isar reference manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf#page=113). Additionally, there is a paper ["Conservative Overloading in Higher-Order Logic"](http://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1094433/1094433.pdf) by Obua that discusses some of the implementation details and gotchas in having such a framework without sacrificing soundness.

Comment: It is important to be aware that these overloaded constants are totally separate: It is not possible to prove any non-trivial property about "is_default (a :: 'a)". So if the various implementations of is_default are supposed to share some formal properties, type classes might be a more suitable mechanism.